# Sublist in Arraylist vs limit in SQL

Tags: java, sql, performance, arraylist

I am working on a grid with pagination.. I have to display 10 rows in a grid each time. So Database may contains max of 1000 rows(mostly wont exceed 500 records).

So will be good to pull all the records and then apply Array.sublist(start, end) OR SQL query with LIMIT(start, end)?

Thanks

Comment: Of course, use database means, to minimize data passed over network.

Comment: Or in the first SQL query fetch only the IDs and then displaying whatever page use a sublist of IDs to fetch the rows.

Comment: How often do you think user explores all 500 records? There are pros and cons of both the approaches.

Comment: It is definitely better to use the database limit. Why have the db work hard fetching entries you know you won't use?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to go with offset and limit. Best applications are when you don't cache too much and you are saving resources. Think more stateless, less you store, better your application works.

If you are using Hibernate you can add caches that will store those records (3-rd level cache -for queries), then Hibernate will cache them for you, but this level of cache is also not recommended.